# How to access value of variable work from export of one 1.tsx file into export of 2.tsx

Tags: react-props, react-typescript

How to access value of variable work from export of 1.tsx into export of 2.tsx, If any other information is required then let me know, I'm new to typescript and react.

I tried context etc but it didn't worked. Also tried to add TrackerData in interface of 1.tsx but also not success.

`**1.tsx****

```
interface Props {
setTrackerData: (trackerData: TrackerData) =\> void;
env: Env;
}

  export default function TrackerInput(props: Props): JSX.Element {

const \[jobID, setJOBID\] = useState\<number\>();
const \[loading, setLoading\] = useState\<boolean\>(false);


async function onGetTrakerID() {}

async function onGetItemsFromTracker() {

    try {
     const trackerId= await getTargetTrakerId(jobID,props.env);
     const **work** = await getJobtype(jobID, props.env);
      const trackerData: TrackerData = { itemSets, trackerId, trackerName ,work,jobID};
      props.setTrackerData(trackerData);
    
    } catch (error) {   
      
    } finally {
     
    }

}

return (
\<Grid container spacing={3}\>
\<Grid item xs={6} md={3}\>
\<TextField type="number" label="Job Id" value={jobID} variant="standard" onChange={onQueryInput} fullWidth={true} /\>
\</Grid\>
\<Grid item xs={6} md={9}\>
\<LoadingButton
loading={loading}
loadingPosition="start"
startIcon={\<SendIcon /\>}
variant="contained"
disabled={!jobID }
onClick={onGetItemsFromTracker}
\\>
Get target items and source items for tracker
\</LoadingButton\>
\</Grid\>

    </Grid>

);
}
```

**2.tsx****

````
interface Props {
items: Item\[\];
env: Env;
}

/\*\*
\*
\*/
export function OriginItemsNotInTargetTable(props: Props) {
const env = props.env;

return (
\<Table size="small" aria-label="purchases"\>
\</Table\>
);
}```
````